# Windows Service With NotifyIcon

Tags: windows-services

I have to develop a TCP/IP server application that will entertain remote mobile clients to connect on some port and interact with each other. My plan is to build it as a windows service so that it may be managed on system level.

> Windows Service

will start automatically listening to port and taking their requirements. A notify icon would be keep showing in system tray. If we will click on this notify icon, a form will be shown with current number of connected clients etc.

I have developed the code and tested it very well it works. But it doesn't show the Form.
Below is the code that starts service from Program.Main()

```
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new Service1() 
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
```

Am i Missing something?

Comment: Services run in session 0, so they can't generate notify icons or otherwise interact with the user.  You'll need to have a separate application to provide the GUI interface.

Comment: Read up about [Session 0 Isolation & GUI services](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#GUIServices)...